# How to bind `item-text` with vue render function

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to render a Vue template using the `render` function **ONLY**.

On this instance I'm trying to bind `item-text` on the attributes object ... but my attempt failed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { color: "blue", hash: "#42A5F5" },
      { color: "green", hash: "#FF4081" },
      { color: "red", hash: "#FF5252" },
      { color: "yellow", hash: "#5E35B1" }
    ]
  }),
  render: function(h) {
    return h("v-app", { attrs: { dark: "dark" } }, [
      h("v-container", [
        h("v-select", { attrs: {
          'items': this.items 
          'item-text' : color // doesn't work  color is undefined
          }
        })   
      ])
     ])
    }
  })
```

So, is there a way to do that using the `render` function only?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/qzGOZv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to map the item object to a color string.

```
h('v-select',{attrs : {'items' : this.items, 'item-text': it=>it.color }}),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a string

```
'item-text': 'color'
```